# Really basic class won't build

Tags: c++

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with this code? I don't get it at all..
I am trying to generate an object out of class "T_Tsunami".
The errors I get are:

"error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall T_Tsunami::~T_Tsunami(void)" (??1T_Tsunami@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main"

and

"fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals".

Header:

```
#include <string>
using std::string;
#include<vector>



class T_Tsunami
{

public:

    // Constructor with default arguments
    T_Tsunami (const int nl = 100, const string="T_Tsunami");
    ~T_Tsunami(); // destructor

    void setNL(int);
    void setNaam(string);

private:

    string Naam;
    int Golf_NL;


};
```

cpp-file:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>

#include "T_Tsunami.h"


T_Tsunami::T_Tsunami (const int nl, const string nieuwe_naam)
{
    setNL(nl);
    setNaam(nieuwe_naam);
}

void T_Tsunami::setNL(int nl)
{
    Golf_NL = nl;
}

void T_Tsunami::setNaam(string nieuwe_naam)
{
    Naam = nieuwe_naam;
}
```

Main:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>

#include"T_Tsunami.h"




int main() {

    T_Tsunami myTsunami;

}
```

Also I don't know if I need to put a return statement in the main, I did try that but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Well the message says it pretty much right there:  unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall T_Tsunami::~T_Tsunami(void)". You did not provide an implementation for the destructor

Comment: A Tsunami IS a destructor:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did *not* define the destructor, such as:

```
T_Tsunami::~T_Tsunami()
{
}
```

Comment: Actually if the destructor does nothing, one should either omit it, make it `inline`, or (in C++11) mark it as `= default`